# Convert JSON to .ics (Python)

Tags: python, json, calendar, icalendar

I am trying to convert a JSON file to an iCalendar file. My supervisor suggested using two functions convertTo(data) (which converts a JSON to a String) and convertFrom(data) (which converts a String to a JSON; I am not sure of the purpose of this function).

My current approach uses a lot of refactoring and multiple functions.

```
#returns a String
def __convert(data):
    convStr = __convertTo(data)
    convStr = __fields(convStr)
    return convStr

#convert JSON to a String
def __convertTo(data):
    str = "" + data
    return str

#takes string arg (prev converted from JSON) to split it into useful info
def __fields(data)
    #########
    iCalStr = __iCalTemplate(title, dtStart, UID, remType, email)
    return iCalStr

#
def __iCalTemplate(title, dtStart, UID, remType, email):
    icsTempStr = "BEGIN:VEVENT\n
                  DTSTART:" + dtStart + "\nUID:" + UID + "\nDESCRIPTION:" + desc + "\nSUMMARY:" + title
    if remType is not None
        icsTempStr += "\nBEGIN:VALARM\nACTION:" + remType + "DESCRIPTION:This is an event reminder"
        if remType is email
            icsTempStr += "\nSUMMARY:Alarm notification\nATTENDEE:mailto:" + email
        icsTempStr += "\nEND:VALARM"
return icsTempStr
```

Any hints or suggestions would be very helpful.  I am fully aware that this code needs a LOT of work.

Comment: This question can become much clearer by adding an example; what JSON object do you want to convert to what ics output?

Comment: Are you asking for code suggestions or are you having a concrete error message or misbehaviour? Does your code compile?

Comment: It's tough to know exactly what you're doing here... but __fields() accepts a data parameter and then does nothing with it. It calls __iCalTemplate with several args that aren't defined in the code you included. Is __iCalTemplate() working against some test data? If so, post that test data and an example of your JSON data. If not... solve that problem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't intended to be a complete answer, but as a longer tip.

There's a Python idiom that will be very helpful to you in building strings, especially potentially large ones. It's probably easier to see an example than explain:

```
>>> template = 'a value: {a}; b value: {b}'
>>> data = {'a': 'Spam', 'b': 'Eggs'}
>>> template.format(**data)
'a value: Spam; b value: Eggs'
```

This idiom has a number of advantages over string concatenation and could eliminate the need for a function altogether if you write the template correctly. Optional inserts could, for example, be given values of ''. Once you format your iCal template correctly, it's just a matter of retrieving the right data points from JSON... and if you name your template insert points the same as what you have in JSON, you might even be able to do that conversion in one step. With a bit of planning, your final answer could be something as simple as:

```
import json
template = 'full iCal template with {insert_point} spec goes here'
data = json.JSONDecoder().decode(your_json_data)
ical = template.format(**data)
```

To do a quick (and slightly different) interpreter example:

```
>>> import json
>>> decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
>>> json_example = '{"item_one" : "Spam", "item_two" : "Eggs"}'
>>> template = 'Item 1: {item_one}\nItem 2: {item_two}'
>>> print template.format(**decoder.decode(json_example))
Item 1: Spam
Item 2: Eggs
```

Comment: I have tried to implement this approach instead of what I was doing before but am having a lot of trouble with decode().  When I try json.decode() I get an error message saying the 'module' object has no attribute 'decode'. When I try json.JSONDecoder().decode() I get an error message reading "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py, line 366
end = self.raw_decode(s,idx=_w(s,o).end()); TypeError: expected string or buffer. Don't know how to interpret that last one.

Comment: Sorry... decode() is a method of the JSONDecoder object. I'll update the answer and provide a quick example.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up using a completely different, more efficient approach to accomplish this.  In summary, my method traverses through a JSON, extracting each value from each field and manually places it in the appropriate place in an iCalendar template.  It returns a string.  Something like this...

```
def convert(self, json):
    template = 'BEGIN:VEVENT\n'
    template += 'DTSTART:%s\n' % json['event-start']
    ...
    return template
```